# can't serialize access for this transaction

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am getting this exception

PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction ; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction

Single batch job is running at one time and no other transaction is happening at the time of creation of Job i am starting a new JOB only when previous one is getting processed.

For Ex. if there is 20 files then i am starting new Job for each file with same JobLauncher with changing the JobParameters. but meanwhile processing i am getting this **exception for some files( that means JOB)**

jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);

JobLauncher is by default synchronous so it will wait untill the job Completes

In for loop i am changing the job parameter by providing different file name so it can execute sequentially one by one.

so few jobs are getting failed every time i am running.
what is the solution ?

**I dont want to change the isolation-level-for-create="SERIALIZABLE" as READ_COMMITTED or something else**

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.1.xsd">

            <bean id="transactionManager"
                            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager" >                             
                            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />                       
            </bean>


            <batch:job-repository  id="jobRepository"
                            data-source="dataSource"
                            transaction-manager="transactionManager"      
                            isolation-level-for-create="SERIALIZABLE"
            />

            <bean id="jobLauncher"
                            class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
                            <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />                                           
            </bean>
            <bean id="jobOperator" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator">
                            <property name="jobExplorer">
                                            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean">
                                                            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
                                            </bean>
                            </property>
                            <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
                            <property name="jobRegistry" ref="jobRegistry" />

                            <property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher">                                     
                            </property>
            </bean>
            <bean id="jobRegistry" class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry" />
            <bean id="jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor" class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor">  
                            <property name="jobRegistry" ref="jobRegistry"/>  
            </bean>
```

Comment: Can you share your configuration?

Comment: @MichaelMinella Hi, I have edited with XML Configuration thanks.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your configuration.  If you can provide a gist that recreates the issue, I can take a look.

Comment: Actually i also don't know what exactly recreating the issue.

Comment: the job is scheduled.